# How to make callback in Angular typeScript?

Tags: typescript

I've got many results through searching but I still don't quite understand.
I have two functions:

```
roulette_animation(){
do animation (might take 5 sec)
}
alertResult(){
alert('You win')
}
```

I want the `alertResult()` function happen after the `roulette_animation()` function is finished.

The `roulette_animation` is done by `js`library which doesn't contain `state` indicates the animation has finished or not.

I know the result in advance for sure, then the animation begins, which will give me the result I want. But the currently the alert will pop up first. The way I am fixing this is to set a time delay between two functions (I can control the duration of animation). But it is not wisely since different browser may load the animation with different speed.

I know more code detail will help but it is just too huge. If this is something I have to add in the `js` I will do it. But I still want to ask is there a way to deal with this asyn problem?

Comment: `an animation based on javascript` <= Please include the code for the animation and/or a reference to the library / call for the animation.

Comment: need way more code if you'd like a helpful answer.  This is clearly asynchronous execution  but "do animation" isn't enough to go on.

Comment: The code is huge... What I am trying to learn is can I make sure certain functions happen in sequence?

Comment: provide a minimum verifiable example as per SO guidelines.

Comment: If it is your own animation library then you need to return a promise from the call which is resolved once the animation has completed execution. If you want further help you need to provide an [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use reactive programming??

```
const animation = (): Observable<boolean> => Observable.of(doAnimation());

animation
  .subscribe(() => alertResult());
```